# The viewModel is null when using hidden field

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I use ASP.NET Core 5 MVC.

I create several tables, th and td dynamically and for each day in a month we create one td with 6 input fields of type="hidden" shown further down.

Each td has its own id.

The problem is the `input type=hidden` fields below. As soon as I use any of these six fields, the viewModel that is passed to controller is null when we submit.

We use these 6 fields to detect when a change has been done in a td cell

This Schedule as you can see in the name attribute for the input field below is part of the viewModel that we pass down to the View and it has this definition.

```
public Dictionary<ShiftTeam, List<Schedule>> Schedule { get; set; }
```

The code we use on the server to add to Schedule looks like this

```
List<ShiftTeam> shiftTeams = adminBusinessLayer.GetShiftTeamsByShiftType(viewModel.ShiftTypeId);

foreach (ShiftTeam stt in shiftTeams)
{
    // For every shiftteam, get the yearly schedule
    viewModel.Schedule.Add(stt, adminBusinessLayer.GetYearlyScheduleByShiftTeam(viewModel.ShiftTypeId, 
                           stt.ShiftTeamId, viewModel.Year));
    viewModel.ShiftTeamList.Add(stt);
}
```

When debugging I can see that Schedule is correct, it contains 5 entries and the TValue is between 200-250 for each TKey

To help to solve my problem I can say the following.

For example this code work. This value is part of the key in the dictionary

```
<input type="hidden" name="@("Schedule[" + i  + "].Key.ShiftTeamId")" value="@stt.ShiftTeamId" />
```

If I change the value I can see that value on the server is correct

This is my first attempt using int as TKey for ShiftTeam

In the view I use this code to produce my first attempt

```
<input type="hidden" name="Schedule[@i].Value[@(totalDays + day)].ScheduleId" value="@Model.Schedule[stt][totalDays + day].ScheduleId" />

<td width="29" id="3_2021-1-1">
    <input type="hidden" name="Schedule[0].Value[0].ScheduleId" value="0">
    <input type="hidden" name="Schedule[0].Value[0].Date" value="2021-1-1">
    <input type="hidden" name="Schedule[0].Value[0].DayTypeId" value="0">
    <input type="hidden" name="Schedule[0].Value[0].HasChanged" value="false">
    <input type="hidden" name="Schedule[0].Value[0].ShiftTypeId" value="7">
    <input type="hidden" name="Schedule[0].Value[0].ShiftTeamId" value="3">
    <a href="#" class="defaultScheduleLink" onclick="showDayTypes($(this));"> - </a>
</td>
```

This is my second attempt

Here I grab the key for ShiftTeam like this

```
var myKey = Model.ShiftTeamList[j];
```

and use it in the name for the first index.

```
<input type="hidden" name="Schedule[@myKey].Value[@(totalDays + day)].ScheduleId" value="@Model.Schedule[stt][totalDays + day].ScheduleId" />

<td width="29" id="3_2021-1-1">
   <input type="hidden" name="Schedule[PPLCore2.Models.ShiftTeam].Value[0].ScheduleId" value="0">
   <input type="hidden" name="Schedule[PPLCore2.Models.ShiftTeam].Value[0].Date" value="2021-1-1">
   <input type="hidden" name="Schedule[PPLCore2.Models.ShiftTeam].DayTypeId" value="0">
   <input type="hidden" name="Schedule[PPLCore2.Models.ShiftTeam].Value[0].HasChanged" value="false">
   <input type="hidden" name="Schedule[PPLCore2.Models.ShiftTeam].Value[0].ShiftTypeId" value="7">
   <input type="hidden" name="Schedule[PPLCore2.Models.ShiftTeam].Value[0].ShiftTeamId" value="3">
   <a href="#" class="defaultScheduleLink" onclick="showDayTypes($(this));">-</a>
</td>
```

This is my third attempt

I use this code to produce my third attempt. Here I have removed the value and use just the index from (totalDays + day)

```
<input type="hidden" name="Schedule[@i][@(totalDays + day)].ScheduleId" value="@Model.Schedule[stt][totalDays + day].ScheduleId" />
    
<td width="29" id="3_2021-1-1">
       <input type="hidden" name="Schedule[0][0].ScheduleId" value="0">
       <input type="hidden" name="Schedule[0][0].Date" value="2021-1-1">
       <input type="hidden" name="Schedule[0][0].DayTypeId" value="0">
       <input type="hidden" name="Schedule[0][0].HasChanged" value="false">
       <input type="hidden" name="Schedule[0][0].ShiftTypeId" value="7">
       <input type="hidden" name="Schedule[0][0].ShiftTeamId" value="3">
       <a href="#" class="defaultScheduleLink" onclick="showDayTypes($(this));">-</a>
</td>
```

The problem must be in the name part of the hidden field.

I can't understand why the ViewModel go nuts for these input hidden field
I have tried everything without any success and I have tried to search for a solution but my problem is very special so it's hard to find any similar.

I mean the name = "Schedule[0].Value[0].ScheduleId" is correct and should work.

The first index which is Tkey and TValue is both 0 so the name should be valid

So all the properties such as ScheduleId really exist in `List<Schedule>` part.

When I use network->Headers to analyze I can see that FormData seems correct

```
FormData
ShiftTypeId: 7
Year: 2021
ShiftTypeId: 7
Header: Skiftscheman
PartialView: _Schedule
ListOfDayTypes: System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.SelectListItem]
Months[0]: true
changeMonths: Ändra
ddlShiftTeams: 3
Schedule[0].Key.ShiftTeamId: 3
Schedule[0].Key.ShiftTeamName: A
Schedule[0].Value[0].ScheduleId: 0
Schedule[0].Value[0].Date: 2021-1-1
Schedule[0].Value[0].DayTypeId: 0
Schedule[0].Value[0].HasChanged: false
Schedule[0].Value[0].ShiftTypeId: 7
Schedule[0].Value[0].ShiftTeamId: 3
Schedule[0].Value[1].ScheduleId: 0
```

//Tony
Hope anyone has a solution to my problem

Comment: Can you share the structure of `ShiftTeam`,and why you want to use a model as the key of dictionary?